# MS-Access 2007: Query all records associated with individuals which have at least one record meeting specified criteria

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to bring 35 years of data into Access from Excel. Part of the cleaning process is making sure the unique ID's we've used for animals we caught are actually unique for each animals.

To do this I want to make sure that each tag only has one "1st capture" associated with it. I can't just search for duplicates because animals are often caught 2-5 times.

Now, I've managed to create that query, which pulls up ID codes with multiple capcode "1" records. (The stuff about id.type is because this is only important for animals that were tagged a certain way)

```
    SELECT [Capture Table].id_code, [Capture Table].capcode, 
    [Capture Table].id_type, [Capture Table].capture_id
    FROM [Capture Table]
    WHERE ((([Capture Table].id_code) In (SELECT [id_code] 
    FROM [Capture Table] As Tmp GROUP BY [id_code],[capcode] HAVING Count(*)>1  And [capcode] = [Capture Table].[capcode])) 
    AND (([Capture Table].capcode) Like "1") 
    AND (([Capture Table].id_type) Like "NP" Or ([All Info Query].id_type)="E" Or ([Capture Table].id_type)="T"))
    ORDER BY [Capture Table].id_code, [Capture Table].capcode;
```

Now, this gives me all the tag numbers that are problems. Now I would like to pull them up with all their associated information (including survey info from tables related to the captures from a specific survey) AND return all records with those ID Codes (so I don't just change the 1st capture and miss any subsequent recaptures).

This returns the records (Session+Header+Capture Query is just pulling all the survey info together with the associated captures, which is how I got around the "ambiguous outer-join error" and can still all the date & site info):

```
    SELECT DISTINCTROW [Session+Header+Capture Query].Year, [Session+Header+Capture Query].site, [Session+Header+Capture Query].Date, [Session+Header+Capture Query].trappers,
     [Session+Header+Capture Query].id_type, [Capcode 1 Repeat subQuery].id_code, [Session+Header+Capture Query].age, [Session+Header+Capture Query].sex, [Session+Header+Capture Query].repro, 
     [Session+Header+Capture Query].tail_mm, [Session+Header+Capture Query].capcode
     FROM [Capcode 1 Repeat subQuery] LEFT JOIN [Session+Header+Capture Query] ON [Capcode 1 Repeat subQuery].id_code = [Session+Header+Capture Query].id_code;
```

So, this now returns all the records associated with the "problem ID codes". However, it also duplicates them (despite have unique records turned on) and is non-updatable.

Long story short, how can I select duplicates with a given criteria (duplicate ID codes where capcode=1) and return all records with those ID codes, not just the ones where capcode=1? While still having my query be updateable?

It seems like the way to do this would be to remove the subQuery and just put the select function into the main one, but I"m not sure how to do that and fold the capcode criteria into that.

Thanks so much for the help!

PS. I'm only still learning SQL, so small explanations in answers along with code are REALLY REALLY helpful, otherwise I just copy and paste and try not to break.

Comment: Since a query can be used as the source for another query, I try to separate complex logic into multiple simpler queries.  So in this case, I would write one query to identify the problem IDs, then use that result in a 2nd query to get all the related records with that ID.

Comment: This is what I had. However, it's not updateable, which is a problem since I'm pulling up the records because they need to be changed and there are over a thousand of them, with over 300 ID's. I didn't want to filter for each ID on it's own to update it. However, I think I figured it out, but you're right, my answer wasn't pretty and looked pretty complicated. I'll post it to share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I ended up figuring out how to do this. I'm posting it here so others can try my weird hodge podge (at their own risk), or so more experienced people can improve upon my best guess at how to do this.

I ended up writing the two queries seperately. The first does what my original first does, pull up all problem IDs. The second pulls up all records related to those. The second also pulls the info directly from the three related tables instead of from the query where everything is combined, which I didn't know how to do before.

Anyway, I combined Query 1 & Query 2 into a single query by placing Query 1 in it's entirety in the WHERE clause of Query 2, so Query 2 only pulled records from the results of Query 1. Each "query" is indented more in the code below.

Suggestions on how to improve this are seriously welcome.

```
    SELECT [Capture Table].*, [Session Table].Year, [Session Table].site, [Session Table].begin_date, [Session Table].end_date, [Header (Survey) Table].Date, [Header (Survey) Table].trappers
    FROM [Session Table] INNER JOIN ([Header (Survey) Table] INNER JOIN [Capture Table] ON [Header (Survey) Table].survey_id = [Capture Table].survey_id) ON [Session Table].session_ID = [Header (Survey) Table].session_id
    WHERE ((([Capture Table].id_code) In 
        (SELECT [Capture Table].[id_code]
         FROM [Capture Table]
         WHERE ((([Capture Table].id_code) In 
            (SELECT [id_code] 
             FROM [Capture Table] As Tmp GROUP BY [id_code],[capcode] 
             HAVING Count(*)>1  And [capcode] = [Capture Table].[capcode])) AND (([Capture Table].capcode) Like "1") AND (([Capture Table].id_type) Like "NP" Or ([Capture Table].id_type)="E" Or ([Capture Table].id_type)="T")))));
```

Comment: You could take the 1st query and change it to a "Make table" query - I think this would allow the 2nd query based on the new table to be editable.